# Cannot GET a post request in node js with axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

i get a Cannot GET /api/auth/signup error every time i try to POST i cant figure it out why
can someone help me with this thanks very much i dont understand what im missing im tryning to post the register in the node js but it keeps telling me   Cannot GET /api/auth/signup

auth.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/";

class AuthService {
  async login(username, password) {
    console.log(username, password);
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + "signin", {
        username,
        password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.accessToken) {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }

        return response.data;
      });
  }

  async logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
  }

  async register(username, email, password) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "signup", {
      username,
      email,
      password,
    });
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  }
}



     export default new AuthService();
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080",
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "it works." });
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are attempting to POST to a route that doesn't exist. You will need to build out your `/api/auth/signup` route in order to send a request to it from axios.

```js
// simple example of post route
app.post("/api/auth/signup", (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  // Your logic to register user in your database

  // Send response after database interaction
  res.status(201).json({ message: 'User signed up for service' })
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer still i cant make a POST request this is what i added   async register(username, email, password) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "signup", (req, res) => {
      let userInput = { username, email, password };
      // Your logic to register user in your database
      users.push(userInput[0]);
      console.log("succses");

Comment: It looks like you added the code to the `register` method? It should be added to the server side code.

Answer (score 0):

For each Specific route you need to implement respective route in your application.
In your application, if you need to have access to two post request of different url, you need to handle two post route.

```
For`/api/auth/signin`

app.post('/api/auth/signin', (req, res)=>{
//Your Implementation here
res.status(201).json({message: 'Your Message'})
})

For`/api/auth/signup`

app.post('/api/auth/signup', (req, res)=>{
//Your Implementation here
res.status(201).json({message: 'Your Message'})
})
```